# V magnitude of binary components

Tags: data-analysis, binary-star, apparent-magnitude

Which catalog provides visible magnitudes of binary components, please? How to find it, for instance, in VizieR, please? I have a list of binaries.

Comment: For which types of binary and which types of star? There are many, many catalogues and none of them are in any way universal.